# Github push commit issue

Tags: git, github, git-push

How to push folders contain of files without remove old commits in github?

I already upload some files to git
But next i upload another file.old ones are deleted

Comment: So you push folders to a repo and your files from that repo dissapear? What command are you using for pushing your new folders?

Comment: Yes Git add . ,git remote add origin 'url_name' , git push -f origin master –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to try to update your repo by doing a `push` you shouldn't run `git remote add origin 'url_name'` in fact trying to run this command gets me this error:

```
*:\***> git remote add origin 'url.git'
error: remote origin already exists.
```

`git remote add origin 'url_name'` [adds a remote to a Git repository](https://careerkarma.com/blog/git-add-remote/#:%7E:text=on%20a%20project.-,The%20git%20remote%20add%20Command,are%20creating%20a%20new%20repository.&text=This%20creates%20a%20reference%20to,on%20GitHub%20called%20demo%2Drepository.) that's why it's deleting your "old" files.

For updating your repo and keep your "old" files use this commands:

```
git status
git add . 
git commit -m "update"
git push origin branch_name
```

In your case `branch_name` is `master`.
Let me know if it worked for you and if it did accept the answer :)